# Is there a way to detect when a cell is shown on the screen?

Tags: gridview, tableview, javafx-8

I'm working on a media player that uses `TableView` and `GridView`. Since loading all the users music at once doesn't perform very well when there are large amounts to load, I wanted to delay loading as much as possible. One of the things I wanted to do for this, was delay loading of the music files until they were visible on the screen. Since TableView and GridView both use cells, I was wondering if there was a way to determine when a cell was shown on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little more research I managed to get something that works. First, here's the two functions I use to get the visible items from the GridView and TableView.

```
public static <T> List<T> getVisible(GridView<T> gridView)
{
    List<T> retList = new ArrayList<>();
    GridViewSkin<?> skin = (GridViewSkin<?>) gridView.getSkin();
    VirtualFlow<?> flow = (VirtualFlow<?>) skin.getChildren().stream().filter(n -> n instanceof VirtualFlow).findFirst().get();

    int firstIndex = flow.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex();
    int lastIndex = flow.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex();
    int cellsInRow = skin.computeMaxCellsInRow();

    retList.addAll(gridView.getItems().subList(firstIndex * cellsInRow, Math.min((lastIndex + 1) * cellsInRow, gridView.getItems().size())));
    return retList;
}

public static <T> List<T> getVisible(TableView<T> tableView)
{
    List<T> retList = new ArrayList<>();
    TableViewSkin<?> skin = (TableViewSkin<?>) tableView.getSkin();
    VirtualFlow<?> flow = (VirtualFlow<?>) skin.getChildren().stream().filter(n -> n instanceof VirtualFlow).findFirst().get();

    int firstIndex = flow.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex();
    int lastIndex = flow.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex();

    retList.addAll(tableView.getItems().subList(firstIndex, lastIndex + 1));
    return retList;
}
```

They're basically the same, but the GridView is actually composed row objects so I needed to multiply by the number of cells per row in order to get the actual indices for the cells.

The next part is exactly the same for both the GridView and TableView. I set up an event listener that listens to all events and then performs whatever action I want on the visible items.

```
TABLE_OR_GRID_VIEW.addEventHandler(EventType.ROOT, evt -> {
    List<ITEM> items = getVisible(TABLE_OR_GRID_VIEW);
    // do whatever you want with the visible items here.
});
```

Comment: I would suggest taking a look at TableColumn.setCellValueFactory, which is the function that will be called when a certain cell must be displayed. You should be able to achieve delayed loading quite easily this way.

Comment: Note that the solution posted here using non-public API. It will not work, for example, in Java 9.

Comment: @rli Are cells removed when they're no longer being shown though? If they aren't it might cause problems with some of the memory saving features the program uses. Since, you know, having (potentially) thousands of songs loaded isn't very helpful to not using a ton of memory.

Comment: @EnderShadow Cells are reused, i.e. the number of cells (by and large) remains constant over time. If the user increases the size of the application window, a few more cells will be created to accomadate the additional cells visible (not sure if shrinking the window will release the cells).

Comment: From some quick testing it appears that the GridView generates all the cells at once. I didn't test it on the TableView, but that makes the entire point of using creation of the cells for loading moot. Using the non-public API seems to be the only reliable way of doing it for my use case at the moment.